# Showing notification independently of the current view PhoneJS?

Tags: jquery, ios, web-applications, knockout.js, phonejs

I'm using [PhoneJS](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/) to make a mobile web app.  It requires a login, and I'd like to show a ['toast' message](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Widgets/dxToast) with the result (error, success, etc)

If the login is successful, it shows a 'success' toast message, and then navigates to the main view of the app.  The problem is, the toast message is hidden as soon as the main view is loaded.  I'd like for it to show for the full 3 seconds, not stop as soon as the view is loaded.

So basically:

1. Login successful
2. Show toast message ("Welcome, John!") while loading main view
3. Main view is loaded, continue showing toast message until time is up (3 sec)

Here's the javascript that is run if there is a successful login:

```
DevExpress.ui.notify("Welcome, you are logged in", "success", 3000 );//I've tried this and dxToast, with the same result for both
AppNamespace.app.navigate("Main", { root: true });
```

The namespace and view is correct, and I've tried both ways to show the notification.  They show very quickly but get replaced by the "Main" view.  I want the notification to show as the view is loading, and continue to show after the view is loaded (until 3 seconds).

The toast message seems to be a part of the 'login' view, but I want it to show independently of the view.  Can this be accomplished?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar bug report at DevExpress support center:

[B238003 - DevExpress.ui.notify: notification is hidden when a view is changed](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=B238003).

It is marked as Fixed, and the updated build is available for download.